# Puis sans proposition antérieure

Tags: expressions, conjonctions

Voici une pub que je viens de voir sur Facebook. Le premier mot : *puis*. Est-ce qu'il pourrait y avoir une raison quelconque de le dire ainsi ? S'agit-il d'un sens informel de *puis* qui m'est inconnu ?

[image: pubsmall]

Comment: Il y a probablement un jeu avec la dernière ligne de la pub... Cela étant dit, *puis* n'est pas une conjonction c'est un adverbe alors... un adverbe... Rien n'interdit de commencer une phrase avec. Si ça fait sens pour celui à qui c'est destiné évidemment... *Et puis flute! tiens! ;-) Encore un truc de publicitaire pour te faire lire la pub.

Comment: Et, quand j'y pense, peut-être un moyen de ne pas commencer une phrase directement par un impératif. Je n'aime pas ça moi les pubs qui commencent par un impératif!

Comment: Rien à voir ici certainement mais... tu n'es pas le premier surpris. Les lecteurs de *la continuation-Gauvain* l'ont été aussi il y a bien longtemps au point que certains copistes l'ont changé ce *Puis* de début de phrase.

Comment: @aCOSwt Hm... je pense que tu as raison, c'est la dernière ligne qui est la clé et donc il est probablement question de format raté. (Ce n'était pas contre sa position en début de la phrase que je protestais, que je considère comme un choix légèrement informel mais stylistique, mais plutôt le manque total d'une proposition liée.) Si quelqu'un propose ça comme réponse — ou, bien sûr, une autre encore plus convaincante — je l'accepterai et oublierai la mésaventure !

Comment: Je ne comprends pas ton dernier comm. Si puis était une conjonction, alors oui, le manque d'une proposition liée serait surprenant. Mais puis, adverbe, c'est bien à dire modifiant le verbe n'a pas besoin (**formellement**) de proposition liée. De nombreux conteurs populaires **commençaient** leurs récits par un adverbe de temps, de lieu...

Comment: @aCOSwt Je ne parle pas de la grammaire mais de la sémantique et de la pragmatique. How many ads do you see that run, "Next, get a good interest rate"? Of what is it the consequence? With the last line it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Encore un cas de définition de terme dans l'acte même de sa première utilisation, ce « puis » ne correspond à rien de ce qui se trouve dans le dictionnaire, tout au moins rien qui soit suffisamment exact ; il est nécessaire de lui donner la signification qui manque ; sans aucun doute les auteurs de ce genre d'innovation dans le langage s'innocentent de toute pratique irrégulière en avançant des arguments à l'effet d'un caractère évident du processus de déduction  qui mène de la forme utilisée et donc de la sémantique associée, à leur concept ; encore une prouesse des agents publicitaires dans le monde de la finance, le « Gagnez et gagnez ! » de la CaixaBank qui remonte a plusieurs  années en arrière, n'est pas un bien meilleur candidat comme archetype de cette sorte d'évidence qu'il faut considérer, nul doute, comme émanente ; faute d'une explication, on ne pourra choisir qu'entre « Gagnez et gagnez tant et plus ! » et « Faites fructifier votre capital et assurez votre succès dans la vie ! », ou peut être mieux et très nouveau, il faudra choisir les deux, une économie de mots sans pareil.

Il y aurais le moyen de rendre à « puis » son sens normal, cela à condition de considérer un contexte extra-linguistique ; le contexte manquant, dans ce cas de « puis  flottant » peut être conçu très largement comme « l'adhérence à l'établissement financier « Tangerine » » ; le premier mot dans cette publicité, Tangerine, suscite un concept à internaliser en tant que révélation, plus, un engagement providentiel ;  ce n'est malheureusement pas une évidence et seulement une devinette. Une paraphrase de la solution de ce « rébus », que certains, dont je suis, préfèreraient lire en toute lettre, peut se tourner comme suit;

> Faites de Tangerine bank votre banque, puis obtenez 3,00 % d'intérêt 
>   Passez à Tangerine bank, puis obtenez 3,00 % d'intérêt
>   …

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi c'est une erreur de traduction. Cette phrase n'a pas de sens.

Étant donné que Tangerine est une banque canadienne, j'imagine que la pub a été faite en anglais et traduite automatiquement.

Dans tous les cas il manque le début de la phrase.

Answer (score 1):

La structure est étrange à n’en pas douter. Détaillons un peu ce qui semble anormal ici.

---

#### Et un agent de liaison en début de phrase, un !

Une phrase commançant par **et**, quoique assez rare, est parfaitement possible. Bien sûr, nous avons généralement un contexte préalable auquel vient s’ajouter le nouvel élément introduit par **et**, contexte assez clairement absent de l’annonce proposée.

Et il y a aussi que **puis**, ce n’est pas **et**. Bien que le québécois moyen utilise allègrement **pis** (tiré de *puis*) comme synonyme de **et**, il confine le plus souvent cette utilisation au domaine oral, et il conservera à la pleine prononciation de **puis** son acception habituelle, qui introduit une suite ou un nouvel élément à la narration. Commence-t-on une phrase par **Puis** ? Ça ne semble pas inusité : [Termium Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=99s3vC8rehnQ.html) propose même une entrée où l’on recommende de ne pas faire suivre ce terme en début de phrase par une virgule.

> Elle était très inquiète. **Puis** elle a fondu en larmes en apprenant la nouvelle.

Il y a cependant ici un contexte. Qu’en est-il de ce **Puis** en entrée de jeu ?

Ionesco, qui écrivait du théâtre moderne, proposa un jour (je serai reconnaissant à la personne qui me retrouvera l’extrait) une conversation entre deux personnes passant sur le trottoir au-delà de la fenêtre de la scène. Leur conversation, faible au début, devient plus forte à mesure qu’ils se rapprochent, puis s’affaiblit à nouveau, pour devenir inaudible juste au moment où le conteur s’apprête à révéler le clou de l’affaire qu’il détaillait. Frustrant, n’est-ce pas ? Un peu comme la vie : on en attrape des bribes, mais le fin mot nous échappe parfois et la vie continue malgré tout.

Est-ce que Tangerine nous proposerait quelque chose de cet accabit ? Probablement pas non plus. Quand on arrive à mi-chemin dans une conversation ou une narration, il peut arriver que l’on se trouve en plein cœur d’une phrase, mais l’écrivain consciencieux indiquerait probablement ce fait par quelque artifice, dont le plus simple serait sans doute de commencer ce qui est entendu par un point de suspension :

- ...et les brosses à dents aussi, j’espère ?

Point de ce genre d’introduction chez Tangerine. On est dans la majuscule à gauche et la police uniforme. Difficile de se raccrocher à ce genre d’argument.

Quel contexte pourrait alors justifier cette utilisation par Tangerine, alors ? J’y vois deux possibilités, les deux nécessitant une campagne publicitaire agressive, et pouvant potentiellement se conjuguer :

- En étant partout, on exposera les clients potentiels à son message plusieurs fois par jour. Le contexte préalable à ce **Puis** commençant l’annonce, inexistant au premier abord, devient rapidement la lecture précédente de ce même message, qui se termine par un élément qui ressemble fort à son introduction, si surprenamment absente.
- On pourrait aussi penser que ce panneau n’est pas l’unique pièce de la série publicitaire. Il n’y a qu’à penser aux couloirs qui mènent aux avions dans les aéroports pour constater que ce qui n’a parfois aucun sens seul prend parfois sa signification dans un groupe. Il semble d’ailleurs *(voir ci-dessous)* que Tangerine ait déjà penser à utiliser cette stratégie publicitaire.

[image]

Il est entendu que nous ne sommes pas ici dans la communication philosophique. Aristote et Kant sont à des années-lumières. Ainsi qu’Homère et Cervantès. Même le discours du candidat d’un petit parti politique a de fortes chances d’être plus élégant. Mais le but de Tangerine n’est pas l’élégance. Ce serait plutôt de convaincre rapidement le client potentiel lambda, qui ne regarde une publicité que quelques secondes.